# Is there a a word for "revealing himself to be foolish by attempting to appear intelligent"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "when one reveals himself to be stupid, ignorant, foolish by attempting to appear intelligent, smart, witty"?

Comment: You might want to check out this question:
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202697/word-for-someone-seeming-deep-and-intelligent-but-not-really-being-that

Comment: "Speaking" : [Si tacuisses, philosophus mansisses](http://everything2.com/title/Si+tacuisses%252C+philosophus+mansisses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a word *sophisticated* which means appearing but only appearing to be clever. It is from a Greek word "sophis", which means facile wisdom. The Greek word for wise is "sophos" - where "sophis" attaches itself as being "wisdom-ish". Looks like wisdom.

In English, like the Greek word, the word *sophist* is of dual mode use. I guess that  is the point - such that when we deploy the word *sophis* on someone, it is deliberately to cast a vague aspersion upon that person.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sophist ...

#### soph·ist  (sŏf′ĭst)

n.

1. a. One skilled in elaborate and devious argumentation.
   b. A scholar or thinker.
2. Sophist Any of a group of professional fifth-century bc Greek philosophers and teachers who speculated on theology, metaphysics, and the sciences, and who were later characterized by Plato as superficial manipulators of rhetoric and dialectic.

[Middle English sophiste, from Latin sophista, from Greek sophistēs, from sophizesthai, to become wise, from sophos, clever.]

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*

#### sophist (ˈsɒfɪst)

n

1. (Philosophy) (often capital) one of the pre-Socratic philosophers who were itinerant professional teachers of oratory and argument and who were prepared to enter into debate on any matter however specious
2. a person who uses clever or quibbling arguments that are fundamentally unsound

[from Latin sophista, from Greek sophistēs a wise man, from sophizesthai to act craftily]

*Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014 © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014*

Comment: Oops ... looks like I've already given an answer to an earlier similar question, and now I remember it. Perhaps, we should delete this question.

Comment: For such questions you can flag or vote to close them as duplicates. I've already done so on this question, the link to do it is directly under the body of the question.