# A phrase to describe on someone who foolishly convinces you he’s intelligent?

Tags: phrase-requests

A person came to another holding an apple in his hand, and reaching it to the person facing him. “I know what’s on your mind, because using the method of Psychology I made you think ‘why you are giving an apple to me?’”confidently flattered himself, the guy thought he impressed someone for another day.

Any good phrase to ridicule such person?

Comment: Can you clarify what was said, because as it is written what the person with the apple says isn't very intelligent

Comment: I'm not trying to imply anything about you. I was wondering if you could try to reword what was said to help understand what you are asking

Comment: What does this part mean:"the guy broke out such amazing words from his mouth"?

Comment: I don’t want to take this seriously because I don’t know if you are just laughing at me or not. Because I thought it was amazingly foolish in an ironic way, for stating the obvious?

Comment: Yea, sure you are the man. So tell me what I needed to do to make it more understandable .

Comment: Because the person with the apple is supposed to be foolish?

Comment: Perhaps he is a "pseudo-profound bullshitter".

Comment: I didn’t mean any offense in my previous comment, but why did it have to be deleted?

Comment: pseudo-profound bullshitter is nice, but as what I posted below, having a suggestion of deceit would be the most accurate. Maybe I should have given another example.

Comment: Wait, maybe it does have a hint of deceit.

Comment: What about the person with the apple is trying to induce one's mind to think it’s a person with an apple, and convincing that he used some advanced techniques to do so.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The title asks one question, but the body ends with a different question.

Comment: Thanks on this guys. I’ll try fixing it sometime tomorrow. I had a headache early in the morning.

Comment: Are you looking for something like 'conman'/'con artist', 'scammer' or 'trickster'?

Comment: Anyway I made a rough change to it. I definitely wasn’t thinking at all when typing. I apologize to any of you who finds me being dumb this time.

Comment: Are you talking about somebody who successfully convinces you he is intelligent (which is what I think the question title implies), or somebody who tries and fails to convince you he is intelligent (which is how I interpret the apple story)?

Comment: Charlatan, BS Artist, ego stroker.  BTW, calling someone a *stoker* would be more insult than ridicule.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe this could help -

> It's not common, but
>   [sciolist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sciolist) seems to have the
>   required definition.
>
> > One who exhibits only superficial knowledge; a self-proclaimed expert with little real understanding.
>
> I prefer this to sophist, which I think has a suggestion of deceit
>   rather than just ignorance or error.

<sup><sup>Source: [Word for someone seeming deep and intelligent, but not really being that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202697/word-for-someone-seeming-deep-and-intelligent-but-not-really-being-that/202747#202747)</sup></sup>

Comment: Actually having a suggestion of deceit was what I was looking for. But thanks on that.

Comment: Good answer. +1.